# How can I merge SMS and Hangouts messages within Hangouts?

Tags: sms, motorola-moto-g, google-hangouts

It made sense to me to merge SMS, WhatsApp style messaging and video calls into one app to save resources and switching between apps so I set up Hangouts to be the SMS app.

I just had one problem - how to send SMS messages from Hangouts? (If I know the person has a problem with data reception, then I do specifically want to send an SMS at that time, for instance.)

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3441321?hl=en-GB/):

"Choose a contact from your conversations list. Touch someone's name at the top. You can then choose SMS from the drop-down menu."

But that is not true in practice. It appears the reason I couldn't do that was because I was in the "hangout" for Hangout messages (I will call it MoIP - Message over IP - in the following) and video calls for that person, not the SMS "hangout" for that person.

Integrating the two in one app and then separating them seems to be going half a step backwards again, so does anybody know if I can merge those two hangouts and do SMS, MoIP and video calls to a person from the same "hangout"?

My phone is a Moto G 1st generation without 4G (XT1032) with Android 5.0 "Lollipop".

Comment: Is the person in reference merged with a contact that has their phone number associated with it? I've found that if I have different contacts for the same person for some reason, or initiate a Hangout in a way that doesn't draw from my contacts, I don't get the option in the corner to switch. But if the contact has both the email address associated with their Hangout conversation AND their phone number in it, I can switch at will, which I do regularly.

Comment: That was probably the problem. I was going to invite for video calls on the SMS hangout and the delete the original video one, but merging hangouts seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you long press on either hangout (MOIP or SMS), then press on the other one you should get an option to merge them. This should then give you the option to send either from the same hangout.

There is also a setting within `Settings` > `SMS` to `Enable merged conversations` which needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a conversation in Hangouts, click on the icon to the left of the text field. That'll give you an option to switch between SMS and hangouts.

Comment: I was hoping I could have something like that - my problem was that there was no SMS option, only MoIP.

Comment: That can be solved by enabling merged conversations.

Comment: And - critically - merging them, once I knew how!

Comment: You need to enable the settings > SMS > Enable merged conversations in order for this option to appear.

Answer (score -3):

Go to settings /sms/default sms account and Change it to your Gmail account